# Ecobee 4 - C Wire Connected but no power

Tags: hvac, thermostat-c-wire, wifi

I have an extremely old HVAC system (Goodman Janitrol Model GMNT060-3) and had a previous WiFi thermostat connected with a C Wire. I am now upgrading to a ecobee4 and cannot get any power to the thermostat. Any ideas?

[image: ecobee wiring][image: previous thermostat wiring][image: wiring diagram][image][image][image][image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you get us a shot of the thermostat connections at the furnace that isn't blurr-o-vision?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - the last two pictures on the edited post should hopefully be better.